# maven deploy-file requires a project to execute but no pom file is found

Tags: maven

I am trying to use maven deploy-file but keep getting this exception:

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.MissingProjectException: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (..)

using this command:

```
mvn -X deploy:deploy-file \
       "-DrepositoryId=Private_Snapshots" \
       "-Durl=https://nexus.di2e.net/nexus/content/repositories/Private_Snapshots/" \
      "-DgeneratePom=true" \  
      "-DgroupId=Generator" \
       "-DartifactId=PConfigurator" \
       "-Dversion=1.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" \
       "-Dfile=./PConfigurator.apk"
```

My settings.xml file contains:

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <id>Private_Snapshots</id>
      <username>USERNAME</username>
      <password>XXXXXXXXXXXX</password>
    </server>
 </servers>
```

If a pom.xml is necessary, what would it look like?
Thanks

I tried adding -Dpackaging=android:apk or -Dpackaging=apk with similar results. There is no space between deploy and :deploy-file.  Here is additional output of the failure:

```
+ /usr/local/apache-maven/bin/mvn -X deploy:deploy-file -DrepositoryId=Private_Snapshots -Durl=https://nexus.di2e.net/nexus/content/repositories/Private_Snapshots/ -DgeneratePom=true ' '
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 13:51:28+0000)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven
Java version: 1.8.0_91, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /opt/jdk1.8.0_91/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/local/apache-maven/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /home/jenkins/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /home/jenkins/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for /home/jenkins/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:pom:1: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.094s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 30 19:55:58 UTC 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/121M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (.). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.MissingProjectException: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (.). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

Comment: are you sure you didn't place a space between `deploy` and `:deploy-file`? in that case maven would give this error thinking you invoked the `deploy` phase, which obviously needs a pom file for execution

Comment: I agree with @A_Di-Matteo. I seems like the most likely explanation. The output from Maven should tell you if the `deploy` phase was activated. Could you please add more output to the post? What does it say before the `MissingProjectException`?

Comment: running simply `mvn deploy:deploy-file` should complain about the missing file or url. If that works, the plugin is executed correctly. Otherwise, I would look into the packaging. It kind of hints that it is looking at that prior to failing.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem. I removed the backslashes in the command and then it worked. So your command would be this:

```
mvn -X deploy:deploy-file "-DrepositoryId=Private_Snapshots" "-Durl=https://nexus.di2e.net/nexus/content/repositories/Private_Snapshots/" "-DgeneratePom=true" "-DgroupId=Generator" "-DartifactId=PConfigurator" "-Dversion=1.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" "-Dfile=./PConfigurator.apk"
```